License of Android NDK missing/not accepted (installed via sdkmanager in commandline)
Fixed by setting ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android_sdk/
(was ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android_sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/).
See: https://developer.android.com/tools/variables#envar

I try to set up a command-line only build environment for Android NDK projects, using commandlinetools-linux-11076708_latest.
I know how to accept the Android SDK licenses "in advance", as described here: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/install-ndk
However, the license of the NDK seems to be missing. All NDK projects (such as hello-jni from https://github.com/android/ndk-samples) I tried to build fail with:
> com.android.builder.sdk.LicenceNotAcceptedException: Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
     ndk;27.0.12077973 NDK (Side by side) 27.0.12077973
  To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.

I believe installing the NDK this way is encouraged nowadays, or do I have to install the NDK manually to be able to accept the license?
sdkmanager --licenses yields:
[=======================================] 100% Computing updates...
All SDK package licenses accepted.

This is how I set up the Android SDK so far (via Docker):
FROM ubuntu:latest

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    openjdk-21-jre \
    zip \
    wget && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN cd /opt && \
    wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-11076708_latest.zip && \
    unzip commandlinetools-linux-11076708_latest.zip -d android_sdk && \
    cd android_sdk/cmdline-tools && \
    mkdir latest && \
    mv bin/ lib/ NOTICE.txt source.properties latest/ && \
    yes | /opt/android_sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager --licenses

//ENV ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android_sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/
// FIXED:
ENV ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android_sdk/

The <android_sdk>/licenses directory contains these licenses:
android-googletv-license
android-sdk-arm-dbt-license
android-sdk-license
android-sdk-preview-license
google-gdk-license
mips-android-sysimage-license


I have encountered the same problem. For the solution, however, I do not create a latest folder within cmdline-tools.
If you rebuild your script like this, it should work:
Unzip: commandlinetools-linux-11076708_latest
Copy the included cmdline-tools folder to a suitable location. E.g. /home/<your username>/android-sdk/
Open a terminal in the cmdline-tools/bin directory and execute the following command: sh sdkmanager --licenses --sdk_root=/home/<your username>/android-sdk
The path to sdk_root is very important here. It must point to the folder before cmdline-tools. In this example android-sdk
For your script, the ANDROID_HOME environment variable must point to /home/<your username>/android-sdk. In your Docker, it points to another location.

Thanks for your post! Your last sentence was the key: My ANDROID_HOME was wrong, it must point to the sdk directory, not to the cmdline tools. See: https://developer.android.com/tools/variables#envar
